# jQuery : find in first level children only (XML)

Tags: jquery, xml

How can we restrict the **find** to search in first level children only in an XML document.

For example:

Consider this XML which is a response from Onet webservice (https://services.onetcenter.org/developer/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report code="27-2011.00">
    <career>
        <code>13-2011.01</code>
        <title>Accountants</title>
        <tags bright_outlook="true" green="false" apprenticeship="false"/>
        <also_called>
            <title>Accountant</title>
            <title>Accounting Manager</title>
            <title>Certified Public Accountant (CPA)</title>
            <title>Staff Accountant</title>
        </also_called>
        <what_they_do>Analyze financial information and prepare financial reports to determine or maintain record of assets, liabilities, profit and loss, tax liability, or other financial activities within an organization.</what_they_do>
        <on_the_job>
            <task>Prepare, examine, or analyze accounting records, financial statements, or other financial reports to assess accuracy, completeness, and conformance to reporting and procedural standards.</task>
            <task>Report to management regarding the finances of establishment.</task>
            <task>Establish tables of accounts and assign entries to proper accounts.</task>
        </on_the_job>
        <resources>
            <resource href="https://services.onetcenter.org/ws/mnm/careers/13-2011.01/knowledge">
                <title>Knowledge</title>
            </resource>
..........................
..........................
.............................
    </explore_more>
    <where_do_they_work>
        <industry href="https://services.onetcenter.org/ws/mnm/browse/54" percent_employed="33">
            <code>54</code>
            <title>Professional, Science, &amp; Technical</title>
        </industry>
    </where_do_they_work>
</report>
```

Here I am trying to layout this data on a modal dialog. So for the purpose I need to handle each of the nodes.

So first I need to find the title. So I have this code I tried.

```
var career = $(xml).find('career');
```

Then I assign the **title** tags text content to a header field

And thus I coded it using

```
$('#myh4').html($(career).find('title').text());
```

But obviously it assigned all **title tags** text to the header.

So simply the question is how can we restrict the find function to the first level children only. Means how to prevent it from digging into next levels children like **also_called**

Answer (score 1):

Use `.children('title').text()` [instead](https://api.jquery.com/children/).

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.